# markdown randomly assign emoji skin color

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a quick way to randomly assign skin colour to an emoji. For example, based on https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji_skin_tones.asp I can see that I have access to a range of skin colours such as the following:

Ideally, if I could write a command to incorporate this into my markdown document, it would be something like the following

```
sample(c(,,,,,), 1)
```

Obviously, this does not work. So I am looking for suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add quotes to signal that these are characters.

```r
sample(c("","","","","",""), 1)
```